# When do Riemann sums converge monotonically?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, integration

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a 'well behaved' function and define $c_n$ by the Riemann sums
$$
c_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\left(\frac{k - \theta}{n}\right)
$$
for some given $\theta \in [0, 1]$. Then obviously $c_n$ will converge to the integral of $f$. Under which conditions on $f$ will this convergence be monotone? In particular, will the convergence be monotone if $f$ is twice differentiable with $f > 0$, $f' < 0$ and $f'' > 0$?

Comment: One obvious class of functions whose Riemann sums have monotone convergence would be functions that do not cross the x-axis within the interval of integration.

Comment: @J.Mangaldan Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but f having a definite sign is not enough to ensure monotonicity. As a counterexample, for theta = 1, take a function with f(0) = f(1/3) = f(2/3) = 1, and f(1/4) = f(1/2) = f(3/4) = 10. Then c_2 = 11/2, c_3 = 1, and c_4 = 31/4.

Comment: "Monotonously" means "in a boring fashion."  "Monotonically" is probably the intended word ;-).

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your final question is no for arbitrary $\theta$.  Specifically, let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt(x)$ for $\epsilon < x <= 1$ and define $f$ however you like for $0 \le x < \epsilon$ << .01, say.  (This can be done in a way that maintains the concavity and twice-differentiability of $f$.)  With $\theta = 3/4$, the sequence of Riemann sums begins (with $n=1$):

2., 2.04667, 2.056, 2.0579, 2.05757, 2.05647, 2.05511, 2.05368, ...,

peaking at $n=4$.  (The sequence is monotonic after that.)

The problem occurs because there is a section at the end of the graph of $f$, in this case near zero, that grows quickly enough to appreciably alter the very first term of the sum once $n$ grows large enough; this section is not sampled by the sum for smaller $n$.  By modifying $f$ appropriately within disjoint intervals converging to 0, you should be able to construct an example whose sequence of Riemann sums wiggles arbitrarily many times.  What this hand-waving argument does not settle is whether this process can be carried out *ad infinitum*: the concern is that the resulting $f$ might not be continuous at 0, which conceivably is part of your concept of "well-behaved" (although it is not necessary for the theory of Riemann integration, which permits some points of discontinuity).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting counterexample. It's a pity that my assertion as stated is wrong - many interesting inequalities would have followed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $f$ is decreasing and convex, it is true that $c_n$ increases monotonically, if $\theta<0$.

The proof is fairly straightforward, left as an exercise to the reader.

[See the question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291617/inequality-monotone-convergence-of-certain-riemann-sum).